# Promedio de un rango de fechas eh horas en JAVA

Tags: java

Buen dia

Estoy creando un informe y necesito saber como podria obtener el promedio con el que susede un evento para esto tengo un arreglo con la fecha y la hora que sucede pero quisiera obtener el **promedio** estoy haciendolo en **java** pero no se me ocurre una manera les agradezco una guia muchas gracias.

Aqui un ejemplo:

2019-01-19 07:40:03 
2019-01-19 07:58:58 
2019-01-19 09:36:40 
2019-01-19 10:07:40 
2019-01-19 10:10:19 
2019-01-19 10:32:32 
2019-01-19 11:03:10 
2019-01-19 11:31:47 
2019-01-19 11:53:09 
2019-01-19 12:28:16 
2019-01-19 13:00:08 
2019-01-19 13:01:53 
2018-09-23 09:53:13 
2018-09-23 09:59:32

Comment: Favor de revisar [ask]

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida, considera compartir el código de lo que haz intentado hasta el momento

Answer (score 0):

Bajo el supuesto de que todas esas fechas son objetos `Date`

si llamas al método `fecha1.getTime()` te devolverá la fecha en formato `Long`. Una vez todas las fechas están en formato Long, podrás sacar fácilmente el promedio de la fecha en formato `Long` y luego convertirlo a formato `Date` como se detalla aquí [Transformar long a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487460/converting-long-to-date-in-java-returns-1970)